# Is there a way to cache mailchimp css on wordpress?

Tags: css, cache, plugin-mailchimp

At that point where I'm playing with load times and scores on Lighthouse, GtMetrix and the like, and am seeing problems? where external css scripts aren't being cached. For example, from mailchimp.com:

[image: no cache :(]

Is there a way to do this locally? With a plugin, preferably? Or is the only way to store a copy of the .css and cache that, every so often checking to see if mailchimp has changed theirs??

Comment: Well, storing a copy and checking to see if it's changing is exactly what a cache is, so it seems like a bad design to put a cache on top of a cache. Caching options are set by the remote server (in this case mailchimp's), so mailchimp is probably setting these cache options for a good reason.

Comment: @mozboz indeed, although it looks like they're *not* caching :/

Comment: So I would surmise they have a reason for doing that